program to change volume of an audio file segmentation fault
I am getting a segmentation fault when running the C program with the following code.
// Modifies the volume of an audio file

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// Number of bytes in .wav header
const int HEADER_SIZE = 44;

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check command-line arguments
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./volume input.wav output.wav factor\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open files and determine scaling factor
    FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (input == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *output = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if (output == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    float factor = atof(argv[3]);

    // TODO: Copy header from input file to output file
    BYTE *buffer = malloc(sizeof(buffer));
    while(fread(&buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, input) != EOF)
    {
        *buffer *= factor;
        fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, output);
    }
    // TODO: Read samples from input file and write updated data to output file

    // Close files
    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
}

I tried editing != 0 to != EOF to see if it would change anything but it did not converted buffer type to pointer but still didnt work can anyone suggest anything more i can do to resolve this thanks

I suggest you open the binary .wav files in "b" binary mode. Some say "it doesn't matter in Linux" but it does matter for portable code.

You have multiple problems. One of the is the use of sizeof(buffer) which will be the size of the *pointer*. But the crash is because you pass invalid pointers to the freadandfwritefunctions. It should not be&buffer, but plain buffer` without the pointer-to operator.

As for another error, a "WAV file" is not only a container with raw audio data. You need to learn about its format, or better yet find a library which will handle everything for you.

fread does not return EOF.
